# javascript injection is not working as it should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-injection

I'm injecting script tags with external files as src and after that I'm calling callback function, to inject HTML. But when I debug it goes like this:

1. Inject jquery.
2. Inject HTML (callback function)
3. Inject rest of script tags.

Can someone explain me how to fix this issue that it work like this?:

1. Inject all scripts.
2. Inject HTML.

Injection.js file:

```
injectJavaScripts([
    "lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "lib/angular/angular.js",
    "lib/angular-route/angular-route.js",
    "lib/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js",
    "src/app.js",
    "src/LoginController.js",
    "src/LogoutController.js",
    "src/MainController.js"
], function() {
    injectHTML();
});

function injectJavaScripts(urls, callback) {
    var elements = [];
    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(url);
        elements.push(s);
    });

    var target = document.body || document.documentElement;
    var i = 0;
    var patchNext = function () {
        if (i >= elements.length) return;
        else if (i > 0) {
            elements[i - 1].onload = null;
        }

        elements[i].onload = patchNext;
        target.appendChild(elements[i]);

        i += 1;
    };
    patchNext();
    callback();
};

function injectHTML() {
    var logged = false;
    var cheapWatcherDiv = document.createElement('div');
    cheapWatcherDiv.setAttribute('class', 'cheap-watcher');
    document.body.appendChild(cheapWatcherDiv);

    if (logged == false) {
        $(".cheap-watcher").load(chrome.extension.getURL('views/main.html'));
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + chrome.extension.getURL('sass/main.css') + '" type="text/css" />');
    } else {
        $(".cheap-watcher").load(chrome.extension.getURL('views/logoutTemplate.html'));
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove this line, I tryed with ready, but now it's without. I'll update my post - @Hacketo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `callback()` on wrong position that is supposed to be called after all scripts are injected. However you are calling after first call to `patchNext`.

Modify you `injectJavaScripts` to invoke `callback()`, when all scripts are injected.

```
function injectJavaScripts(urls, callback) {
    var elements = [];
    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(url);
        elements.push(s);
    });

    var target = document.body || document.documentElement;
    var i = 0;
    var patchNext = function () {
        if (i >= elements.length) {
            // All scripts are injected now
            // ok to invoke callback() here
            callback();
            return;
        }
        else if (i > 0) {
            elements[i - 1].onload = null;
        }

        elements[i].onload = patchNext;
        target.appendChild(elements[i]);

        i += 1;
    };
    patchNext();
    // callback(); don't call here
};
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! It works now fine - @AdnanUmer